# Selenium using Firefox driver -Tries to connect to random port number ," Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:******/"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I've been trying to run selenium webdriver in firefox for a while and I always get the same error :Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:******/"(The number is changing constantly)
I have experience with using selenium with Chrome but never used it on Firefox.
I had followed a tutorial which always work for me with chrome-webdriver that can be found here : https://medium.com/@tanveer.khan/dotnet-core-selenium-nunit-visual-studio-code-2d489ccb2089
I have installed the geckodriver.exe and placed it in multiple places(Tried bunch of solutions that were proposed online) , such as firefox browser location, project location and etc.
From here : https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
I had installed all packages needed from :dotnet add package ...
I had never chosen where the driver will navigate, it seems like it does this automatically.
all I need is for the test to successfully pass, just by not doing anything.

source code :

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace DemoFox
{
    class Program
    {
        
        
         IWebDriver driver;
       
         [SetUp]
     public void TestSetup()
    {  
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("geckodriver.exe",@"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox");     
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:3001");
    }
    [Test]
    public void FirefoxTest(){
    Console.WriteLine("Hello firefox");
}
[TearDown]
    public void TestTearDown(){
        driver.Quit();
    }

}
}
```

Exception message :

Outcome: Failed
Error Message:
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:58696/
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stack Trace:
at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxDriverService service, FirefoxOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxOptions options)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor()
at DemoFox.Program.TestSetup() in c:\Users\Lab\Desktop\FireFoxDemo\DemoFox\Program.cs:line 24
--TearDown
at DemoFox.Program.TestTearDown() in c:\Users\Lab\Desktop\FireFoxDemo\DemoFox\Program.cs:line 33
Standard Output Messages:
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:58696 (localhost:58696)

Total tests: 1. Passed: 0. Failed: 1. Skipped: 0

Comment: Just to make sure I understood your question:
Why are u using ports? It's to get hold of a already open process?

Comment: I want to connect to a server that runs locally on my computer. but for the first part, I just want the test to print to the console, but it fails in the setup stage even when there is only one line of code there : driver= new FirefoxDriver();.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with driverpath :

```
 [SetUp]
 public void TestSetup()
{  
    var driverpath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Driver"; //find the      driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverpath);
      
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:3001");
    
    driver.Manage().Window.FullScreen();
    
}
```